# firebase $getIndex() usage

Tags: angularjs, firebase

When I run `$getIndex()` on my projects node I get an empty array. Why? and am I using it incorrectly?

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/G55jS/1/

**js**

```
angular.module('todo', ['firebase']);

angular.module('todo').controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $firebase) {
  var projectsUrl = "https://ionic-guide-harry.firebaseio.com/projects/";
  var projectRef = new Firebase(projectsUrl);
  $scope.projects = $firebase(projectRef);
  $scope.projects.$on('loaded', function() {
      $scope.keys = $scope.projects.$getIndex();
  });   
});
```

**html**

```
<div ng-app="todo" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div ng-view>
        {{keys}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Screen cap of my data layout

[image: firebase forge]

Comment: Not sure but I think I've encountered something related in the past: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/276 - I was suggested a workaround using https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#on-eventname-handler but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it's a known bug and has been fixed. Will be fixed in the upcoming release https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/262

Update: the fix was merged into the [0.7.1 release](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/releases/tag/v0.7.1)